# I am transfering ethereum but showing 0 value and the transaction is successful

Tags: web3j

I am using web3j method sendFunds to transfer ether deducting the fee the transaction successful but showing 0 value in etherscan 
[Here is the link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbe39efe5e876f5d037d15c76f0adc75274095be6)

Comment: Both transaction that appear in your account are successful with 0 value transfered. Show us your code to try to determine if it is correct or point to the bug.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael the problem was with my code. It worked now :)
But I didn't understand why it still showed success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the same the problem was with my fee calculation.So it was showing value of 0.